# Bound for the number of roots $\rho$ of $\xi(\rho)$

Tags: complex-analysis, number-theory, riemann-zeta, riemann-hypothesis

I was reading the book *Riemann's Zeta Function*, by H. M. Edwards, page 42, where is a theorem that estimates the number of roots of the $\xi$ function
$$\xi(s)=\Gamma\Big(\frac{s}{2}+1\Big)(s-1)\pi^{-s/2}\zeta(s),$$
built with the Gamma function and Riemann's Zeta Function. The estimation is inside or on the circle $|s-\frac{1}{2}|=R$. Below is the screenshot of the theorem and the proof.   [image]

There is one step of this proof that I don't understand. How is proven the last inequality? The one that establish that 
$$\frac{2}{\log 2}R\log R+ 2R-\frac{\log\xi(\frac{1}{2})}{\log 2}\leq 2R\log R.$$

Comment: At first this is a mistake. Do you really care of the constant at this point ? The theorem about the density of zeros is proven in every text about $\zeta(s)$.

Comment: @reuns I wouldn't care about the constant, if it can be shown that the order of the number of roots is at most $R\log R$. Can you give me a reference to find an alternative proof to this fact?

Comment: It should be in your book. The density theorem is $\sim$ not $\le $ and it follows [those lines](https://fr.wikipedia.org/wiki/Fonction_z%C3%AAta_de_Riemann#La_fonction_S(T)), otherwise look in [Titchmarsh](https://zulfahmed.files.wordpress.com/2018/08/titchmarsh-and-d-r-heath-brown-the-theory-of-the-riemann-zeta-function.pdf)

Comment: I got it. The proof given by Edwards shows under the table that the order of the number of roots is at most $R\log R$. Thank you for your clarification @reuns